# Custom loss function depending on model predictions in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with the TensorFlow backend. I am trying to implement the objective function described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06042) (Globally Normalized Transition-Based Neural Networks). The gist of it is that I need an objective function that depends on the current network and its predictions. It takes the training sequence and looks at how well the network predicts this sequence, and switches between two objective functions based on that. The ultimate objective value depends on the predictions of the model.

I have already written a custom loss function that allows me to access the model (inspired by [this discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2121)):

```
def global_norm(model):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        print model.weights #To check if the model is available
        return (y_true - y_pred) #Dummy objective function
    return loss
```

and compiled the model:

```
model.compile(loss=global_norm(model), ...)
```

After starting the network training it prints out a list of model layers once, then never again. I understand that the loss function is only called once, after which it is turned into a 'gradient'. Is there any way to call the objective function for each sample? Or do I need a different approach?

EDIT: To clarify: the two objectives it is switching over are gradients, and the optimizer should take a gradient step along this function. I think it should work if the objective function is called for each sample.

Comment: The objective function is called once for compilation, then it becomes a tensor that is evaluated on each output (batch-wise). But I really didn't get your point. Do you need some control-flow in your objective function for instance ?

Comment: I guessed so! I want the objective function to compile at every training sample, because the control flow I need cannot be represented by a tensor (I think). Using beam search, it looks at whether or not the training sequence falls within the beam predicted by the model. For that I need the latest model for every training sample. But maybe there is a better way for me to do it, like write my own optimizer? Would that work?